# How to make a "lock" on image that when downloaded will corrupt it?

Tags: image, png, jpeg

With intellectual property becoming a harder and harder area to protect with copyright, one particular area I have been thinking a lot about is images like .jps and .png

I was wondering if there is any way to make a mini "bomb" per se that when an image is uploaded to a website, nothing happens, it's perfectly fine and stays there but when downloaded by someone other than the original uploader, the .jpg or .png corrupts itself and cannot be viewed.

I have tried to research the topic but all I am able to find is how to's on how to fix corrupted images or files.

TL;DR
When an image file is downloaded from the host website the image corrupts itself from being viewed.

Comment: Well browsers are reading your file from the source. And unless your file is some related Javascript it will not execute client side. What you're trying to do will require client side code execution. Maybe just stick with DRM?

Comment: That might be the easiest way because it already exists, I was just wondering if it would even be possible to develop my own solution that do something of the sort and if there were any resources I could use as a place to start looking into it.

Comment: Encryption maybe? Let the user download an encrypted version and send the decryption key separately.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan actually a bit tedious but a good starting point. Thanks!